# laravel 4 social with simple auth wrapper

Tags: authentication, oauth, laravel-4

I start using laravel (ver 4) and I got to the point I need to use authentication on my website.

I tried to find package that will allow me to wrap the all idea of "standard" / simple authentication and the social one (like facebook, google+ and etc..).

I found ion_auth and with some extensions it's allow me to use one authentication library for all kind of users - but it only works in codeigniter framework.

After a lot of research I couldn't find any ready package that allows me what I'm looking for, Does anyone familiar with such library or had this kind of issue and can tell me how he handle it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a paid library, but it works pretty well. https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry-social

Comment: This is what i'm looking for but only without a cost.

Answer (score 0):

i had a good experience using [artdarek/oauth-4-laravel](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel). it also has got a nice set of examples for using with different login providers.

Comment: It is allow the social authentication but not simple authentication.
I'm looking for something that will provide me the entire users system - with databases and allow me both social and simple authentication / register.